# Is there something wrong with this SIM card circuit

Tags: sim

I have been troubleshooting a SIM card circuit for a few days now but cannot get it to work. The purpose of this circuit is to connect a quectel bg95 to a sim card so that I can connect to my cellular provider.  Initially I made a few mistakes such as using the wrong capacitance on the data lines, but now I am just sitting here wondering what could be wrong.

I am using a Molex micro SIM holder [datasheet](https://componentsearchengine.com/Datasheets/1/78723-1001.pdf) with contacts C1-C8, but my application calls for connecting to VDD, RST, DATA, CLK, and GND.  Below is my correlation from C# contact to data labels, and I am pretty confident that they are correct.

```
Vdd  --> C1
RST  --> C2
CLK  --> C3
GND  --> C5
Data --> C7
Case --> GND
```

But my module cannot read/connect to this SIM card and I know this from AT command results and the firmware of the module is programmed to bring SIM Vdd to 1.8V at boot but then remove voltage from Vdd if no SIM is detected within the first few seconds, which I am observing.

Below is my circuit, hardware integration manual circuit, PCB footprint, card holder footprint close-up.  Does anyone see potential issues with this circuit that I am missing?  Are there any potential tests that I can perform to look for the problem?  For the layout, all other components but the sim holder are on the top layer, the holder is on the bottom layer of the PCB.

My Circuit
[image: circuit]

Hardware integration manual circuit
[image: hardware integration circuit]

My PCB layout
[image: pcb layout]

Close-up of SIM holder

[image: pcb layout close-up]

Comment: what does a sim card datasheet say?

Comment: it's attached but nothing this is why I am confused.

Comment: scope traces of the protocol would be the next logical step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circuit diagram and layout turned out to be fully functional after several days I decided to buy another SIM card.  After replacing the old SIM everything worked fine!  I will leave up this post though just in case someone needs a reference circuit and layout for a SIM circuit in a similar application.